# How to add additional attribute in ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool on User Registration?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, roles, administration

Hi I want to add additional attribute when a user is register through ASP.NET WebSite Administration Tool . By default when we register use from administration tool , it contain password , username , security answer etc. I want to add additional field like address in it . There is a way to doing it .

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, please try this:

in web.config:

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProfileProvider">
<providers>
<remove name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"/>
<add name="SqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"     connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" />
</providers>
<properties>
<add name="Address" type="string"/>
<add name="Age" type="int32"/>
</properties>
</profile>
```

In codebehind:

```
Dim userProfile As ProfileBase
userProfile = ProfileBase.Create("desired user profile", True)
userProfile.SetPropertyValue("Address", "123 Avenue")
userProfile.SetPropertyValue("Age", 21)
userProfile.Save()
```